# MVC: split string from model in multiple text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model:

```
public class Data
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string BBBCode { get; set; }
}
```

Part of view:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BBBCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BBBCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

for this model, Visual studio created an edit view with text box for the `BBBCode` member. But I need to split `BBBCode` in two textboxes, first text box should have maximum 4 characters and the second text box should contain the rest of the characters. Is there a way to achieve this automatically or without any javascript code and without modifying the model?

Comment: have your tried custom editor template ?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan No. Can you please send me a link or something? I'm new to MVC and I know only the basic stuff. Thanks

Comment: try this: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm
and you can search for this like: MVC Editor Templates

Comment: but as an advice I'll say you.Your View is wanted 2 textboxes for your model.But your model has only the one which must be changed.So it will be good if you make a ViewModel(about ViewModel search).In ViewModel there is everything that your View want.So in the VIewModel you can have 2 separate strings(BBBCode pieces) and give your View's Model to that ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, your viewmodel should correspond to the form you actually render. Mostly if `Data` belongs to business logic. I.e:

```
public class Data
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string BBBCode { get; set; }
}

public class DataViewModel
{
     public DataViewModel() 
     {
     }

     public DataViewModel(Data data) 
     {
          id = data.id ; 
          BBBCodePartOne = ... ; 
          BBBCodePartTwo = ... ; 
     }

     public int id { get; set; }
     public string BBBCodePartOne { get; set; }
     public string BBBCodePartTwo { get; set; }

     public Data ToData() 
     {
         return new Data() { id = id,  BBBCode = BBBCodePartOne  + BBBCodePartTwo } ;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do it in your View model i mean like this:

```
public class Data
{
     public static char Separator = '-'; //here is your separator
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string BBBBegin { get; set; }
     public string BBBEnd { get; set; }
     public string BBBCode { get { return BBBBegin + Separator + BBBEnd; } }
}
```

Now on your View you always can do it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BBBBegin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BBBEnd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BBBBegin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BBBEnd, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

And when you post it to controller you always can get full BBBCode from `BBBCode` property.

Comment: and when I will want to save the model, will it automaticaly populate BBBCode with the text from those two text boxes?

Comment: @BudaGavril you should just understand wht will happened. You post form with your textboxes, then MVC will bind values to `BBBBegin` `BBBEnd` properties. Then you can just get full code from `BBBCode` property. i suppose it's pretty clear how it will work

Comment: I understand that, but I've asked if there's a way to bind automatically those two text boxes to my property when the model is validated.

Comment: @BudaGavril yes there is. You should create your [`CustomModelBinder`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) but it's really now wotrh it. It's better to extend existing model or create ViewModel like @Ksv3n advice you

Answer (score 0):

You should use two property in your model.

```
public class Data
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string BBBCode1 { get; set; }
     public string BBBCode2 { get; set; }
}

<div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BBBCode1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BBBCode1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BBBCode2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BBBCode2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

in your controller

```
public ActionResult Index(Data model){
    var bbcCode = model.BBCCode1 + model.BBCCode2;
}
```

Comment: My model is an entity and it has only one member for this code and I want to be automatically populated when I edit the data.

Comment: you shouldn't use your entity as a view model. You should create a new view model class so you should use it in your view  as model. After that populate data in your controller like my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the Model (no judgement)
I used these two in my input field, one for both parts of the value:

```
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Betrag, new { @Value = Model.Betrag.ToString().Split(',').GetValue(0) })</div>

<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Betrag, new { @Value = Model.Betrag.ToString().Split(',').GetValue(1) })</div>
```

This simply splits up a value like '15,00' into a '15' and '00', you can then join the values together again afterwards with some Javascript and JQuery. This works great for me.